# C++ comparison using strings for operators

Tags: c++, operators, compare, string-comparison

I was writing out the function below, and started to think that there's probably a better way to go about it; however Google isn't turning up much, so any insight would be appreciated. I also have a very similar situation involving integers.

```
bool compare_strs (std::string operator_, std::string str_0, std::string str_1)
{
    if (operator_ == ">")
    {
        return str_0 > str1;
    }
    else if (operator_ == "<")
    {
        return str_0 < str1;
    }
    else if (operator_ == "<=")
    {
        return str_0 <= str1;
    }
    else
    {
        return str_0 >= str1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the operator have to be a string?

Comment: Your variable names make baby Bjarne Stroustrup cry.  Also, what happens if someone passes 'lol' for operator_?  It will behave like '>='.  This is probably not intended behavior.  Furthermore, why do you need to do this?  It would help if you posted more code.

Comment: You could make a `std::map<std::string, std::function<bool(const std::string &, const std::string &>>` to store them. There's already premade operator functors in `<functional>`.

Comment: @Wug your spelling of Bjarne makes him cry.

Comment: @chris: The question is not tagged C++11, but it's still a good suggestion that can be adapted to any standard with slightly different syntax.

Comment: hahahahaha this always gets me: (Danish pronunciation: [ˈbjɑːnə ˈsdʁʌʊ̯ˀsdʁɔb]);

Comment: @Wug, True, though half the questions that allow C++11 aren't tagged, so I might as well give the newest solution I can. In C++03, use function pointers or `boost::function`.

Comment: @Wug Well, it doesn't need to involve `std::function`. You can use `std::map<std::string, bool(*)(std::string const&, std::string const&)>`. Can't use functors anymore, but should work otherwise.

Comment: I'm not sure there's something so severely wrong with the original approach to justify employing all the aforementioned technique. removing all the curly braces and elses as well as adding the trailing return or throw or whatever handling should do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a map to store operators and related functors. In C++11, something along these lines should work, though there might be a couple subtle errors. In C++03, you'll have to change a couple things, including changing `std::function` to `boost::function` or function pointers, as well as using `std::make_pair` to store the map values.

```
#include <functional> //for std::function and std::less et al.
#include <map> //for std::map
#include <stdexcept> //for std::invalid_argument
#include <string> //for std::string

struct StringComparer {
    static bool compare( //split up to fit width
        const std::string &oper, 
        const std::string &str0, const std::string &str1
    ) {
        MapType::const_iterator iter = operations.find(oper); 
        if (iter == std::end(operations)) //check if operator is found
            throw std::invalid_argument("No match for provided operator.");

        return iter->second(str0, str1); //call the appropriate functor
    }

private:
    using MapType = std::map< //makes life easier, same as typedef
        std::string, 
        std::function<bool(const std::string &, const std::string &)>
    >;

    static const MapType operations; //a map of operators to functors
};

const StringComparer::MapType StringComparer::operations = { //define the map
    {"<", std::less<std::string>()}, //std::less is a functor version of <
    {"<=", std::less_equal<std::string>()},
    {">", std::greater<std::string>()},
    {">=", std::greater_equal<std::string>()}
};
```

You can also [see it in action](http://liveworkspace.org/code/286cba105526afe42dbd33848cdc4244). The nice thing about an approach like this is that it's very easy to include more operators, as all you have to do is add them to the map.

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about `<functional>`. That's quite neat. Do `std::less` etc automatically cast to integer or perform a string logical operation? (which I'd assume would be a character-wise comparison until one string terminated)

Comment: @slugonamission, To put it bluntly, *Uses operator< on type T.*. See a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less).

Comment: So yes, performs the logical operation on the templated type. Still neat :). Cheers.

Comment: @slugonamission, It's whole use is for something along these lines. Consider `std::map` itself, which requires being sorted. You can specify `std::greater<T>` as an optional argument to the constructor to have it ordered backwards, but all it is is a default parameter that defaults to `std::less<T>`.

Comment: Minor optimization: You should store the result of `operations.find(oper)` instead of going through the map a second time using `operations[oper]`.

Comment: @chris - yeah, it'll save having to write a few callbacks for simple sorting etc too. I was just asking in the first instance because I took the OP's question as implicitly casting to `int` when doing the operation. Tired post-work brain for you...

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you should first ask yourself why you are doing this - there is likely a better solution.  Going with this though, I might do something like:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
bool mycompare(std::string operator_, const T1 & _lhs, const T2 & _rhs)
{
    if (operator_ == ">")
    {
        return _lhs > _rhs;
    }
    else if (operator_ == "<")
    {
        return _lhs < _rhs;
    } 
    //etc.
    else
    {
        throw new exception("Invalid operator");
    }
}
```